# none of the 'wipe free space' programs work-why?

Tags: windows

I have tried Eraser, sdelete, Shred agent & others-none has successfully wiped the free space on my
hard drive.
Using Easeus Data Recovery, I am able to recover over 400,000 files-all intact (including ebooks, and gif, tif and icon files).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would assume its because your settings for those programs are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only doing a single pass, the data would still be "easily" recoverable.  Most corporate/government/military agencies require multiple passes of alternating bits to wipe data out "completely"...  But even that isn't 100%.

When I worked for a large corporate bank, we were required to use a military-grade wiping software and run at least 15 passes, with the passes alternating between writing all 0's on one pass, then all 1's on the next, for each drive we had to wipe.

Here are some references for you:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_erasure

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_remanence (This is the one that will answer your question)

To paraphrase:

"Data remanence is the residual representation of data that remains even after attempts have been made to remove or erase the data. This residue may result from data being left intact by a nominal file deletion operation, by reformatting of storage media that does not remove data previously written to the media, or through physical properties of the storage medium that allow previously written data to be recovered."

Comment: I'm having a hard time believing that consumer software on modern hardware will be able to recover anything with just one pass of 0s, assuming that the hard drive being wiped was modern as well. The page you linked on data remanence says as much.

Comment: Believe what you will, but anything is possible.  and since neither you nor I work in data recovery, we aren't qualified to do more than make broad assumptions about what could be done.  I also believe whether the hardware is modern or not has no real bearing on this process, as it's handled on a software level, not hardware.

Comment: You are right that recovery is possible. However, it is most certainly *not* possible using only software – after a location has been overwritten, the operating system *cannot* read previous data – the disk controller simply does not give it such information.

Comment: That's has nothing to do with my point at all, he asked a question as to how it could happen, I gave links to the data that answers his question.  According to the OP's question, it certainly *IS* possible, otherwise, he wouldn't be asking.  If I had to guess, I would say that the tools he's using aren't effective.

Comment: Actually, re-read the source material I linked.  Nowhere in there does it say it isn't possible, just that "most cases" require special equipment.